# Cake php count distinct

Tags: cakephp

How can this Cakephp query be made to count distinct?

```
        $matches = $this->Product->find('count', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                "Product.brand_id" => $brand['Brand']['id'],
                'Product.active' => 1

        ));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$matches = $this->Product->find('count', array(
    'fields' => 'DISTINCT Product.brand_id',
    'conditions' => array("Product.brand_id" => $brand['Brand']['id'],
            'Product.active' => 1)
    ));
```

Comment: I recommend using a virtual field here instead. And a group by statement.