# How to count Array only if new id

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

if i wanna count this array something like this:

```
$customerOrder = $this->Order->find('count', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Order.customer_id >=' => '1',
                    'Order.status' => 'Delivered'
                )
            ));
```

I only wanna count $customerOrder if Order.customer_id have new id number.

fx: if id 1 have delivered 5 orders then i dont wanna count as 5, but only as 1 new order.

Comment: You have to has some logic  with database to accomplish this job. What's your database structure?

Comment: In raw SQL you'd do `COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id)` no idea in cacke though

Comment: thanks for your answers. Unfortunately, I'm new so do not know exactly what you think when asking about database structure?
if I have an array (1,2,3,4,1,1,5)
Count (array) = 7
But i will only count same number 1
So i should get: 5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332557/cake-php-count-distinct

Comment: Thanks @shudder. 
I have solved now :)